# ASP.NET Core 3.0 Redirect HTTP 4XX and 5XX requests to customized error pages while keeping the error code

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm looking to redirect HTTP requests with 4XX or 5XX error code to a custom error page, while keeping the error code at the request level. I also want to redirect exceptions to a custom error page, with an error code 500.

For that I used in my Startup file
"app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
app.UseExceptionHandler("/error/500");"
associated with an Error controller.

The part about exceptions works well.
I also manage to redirect non-existent routes to my custom page while keeping the 404 error.

However, I can't redirect the following actions to my custom error pages:

- return NotFound()
- return BadRequest()
- return StatusCode(404)

What would be the technical solution applied to accomplish this?

Here is the Configure function of  my Startup file :

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
app.UseExceptionHandler("/error/500");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "Error-StatusCode-Route",
        pattern: "error/{statusCode}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "InternalServerError" }
);

endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could custom middleware to deal with it:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{   
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error/500");     
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        await next();
        var code = context.Response.StatusCode; 
        var newPath = new PathString("/error/"+code);
        var originalPath = context.Request.Path;
        var originalQueryString = context.Request.QueryString;
        context.Features.Set<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>(new StatusCodeReExecuteFeature()
        {
            OriginalPathBase = context.Request.PathBase.Value,
            OriginalPath = originalPath.Value,
            OriginalQueryString = originalQueryString.HasValue ? originalQueryString.Value : null,
        });

        // An endpoint may have already been set. Since we're going to re-invoke the middleware pipeline we need to reset
        // the endpoint and route values to ensure things are re-calculated.
        context.SetEndpoint(endpoint: null);
        var routeValuesFeature = context.Features.Get<IRouteValuesFeature>();
        routeValuesFeature?.RouteValues?.Clear();

        context.Request.Path = newPath;
        try
        {
            await next();
        }
        finally
        {
            context.Request.QueryString = originalQueryString;
            context.Request.Path = originalPath;
            context.Features.Set<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>(null);
        }              
    });
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    //...
}
```

For your ErrorController:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult InternalServerError()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [Route("error/404")]
    public IActionResult StatusCode404()
    {
       //redirect to the StatusCode404.cshtml
        return View();
    }
    [Route("error/400")]
    public IActionResult StatusCode400()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using core3, then this is a known bug. This bug will be fixed in 3.1.
Here is a link to the issue: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13715

For now there is a workaround. You can add this code right after you call `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");`

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.SetEndpoint(null);
    return next();
});
```

This will render your custom pages when you return NotFound or BadRequest from your controller action.